# JavaScript Map.get(variableName) is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react router to pass an Id via the URL parameter and setting my variable like `let { posterId } = useParams();`

This seems to be working as expected because I can write it out in the JSX just fine `<h1> This is a specific poster {posterId}</h1>`

However, when I try to use it to get from a map that I am passing via props it returns undefined from the map `props.postersMap.get(posterId)`.

I verified that the map is populated and if I hard code the .get method to the variable value it works as expected. Is there something I am just overlooking?

Edit: full component code

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Poster(props) {
    let { posterId } = useParams();

    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(props.postersMap)}
            {console.log(posterId)}
            {console.log(props.postersMap.get(posterId))}
            {props.postersMap.get(posterId) ? <p>{props.postersMap.get(posterId).band}</p> : <p></p>}

        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is what my console.logs are showing

[image]

Comment: We need to see your code in order to debug it. Single lines from different areas isnt enough. Please edit your question to add it in.

Comment: If a `Map.prototype.get` returns `undefined` - it means the key is not found. As simple as that. It's either wrong name, or the `Map` is filled later than you request it.

Comment: Why does this have close votes for "Off Topic"?

Comment: @NikKyriakides I didn't close-vote but "It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"

Comment: @NikKyriakides thankfully we have enough rep to reopen it should it happen ;-)

Comment: Do see [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing): the consensus is to close ASAP. If it gets clarified after an edit, it can be reopened.

Comment: Added full component code @zerkms

Comment: @CertainPerformance My bad, if there's a consensus on how this should be dealt, ignore me and sorry for abusing the comments on this one :)

Comment: @Cogorlopez as per that code - if you still receive `undefined` it only means that at the moment it's invoked there is no key with `posterId` value in the map.

Comment: `get({posterId})` is wrong, you don't want braces there. If you're setting your value like this, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @LucioPaiva still no luck despite removing brackets

Comment: show that `console.log(props.postersMap.keys.map(k => k === posterId))` ?

Comment: Show the `typeof posterId`. If it's a string - it's expected it's not found.

Comment: @zerkms `typeof posterId` is showing as a string

Comment: @Cogorlopez here you go, see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js `Map` keys must match exactly: if keys are numbers (and they are in your case), then you retrieve them using numeric values.

`props.postersMap.get(Number(posterId))` would do.

Or guarantee you're providing a valid numeric any other available way.

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks for the suggestion, I was pulling my hair out for an hour. Turns out map.get(id + "") worked while map.get(id) returned undefined -_-. 

JS, I swear...